# How to change two factor authentication code lifetime in Asp Net Core Idenity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have tried this, but it didn`t help me:

```
services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(x => x.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Configure ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

To configure the system to use a key lifetime of 14 days instead of the default 90 days, use SetDefaultKeyLifetime:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
```